# Is exclusive disjunction possible in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, restrictions

I would like to get from database some rows and I would like Hibernate to stop checking second part of `OR` condition when the first part returns some data. This is something similar to exclusive disjunction. My code is below:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long now = c.getTimeInMillis();

Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.and(
        Restrictions.lt("start", now),
        Restrictions.gt("end", now)),
    Restrictions.and(
        Restrictions.gt("start", now),
        Restrictions.lt("end", now)))
```

It returns rows which meet the first part of condition and also its second part. How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: You can always implement by truth table: a and not b or b and not a.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this isn't working in my case

Comment: How come? Can you explain what prevents it from working?